# Psensor customize label add space

Tags: 20.04, cpu, lm-sensors, psensor

I am using Psensor and using the the label feature of sensors which allows Ubuntu top bar to show the temps and usage, but currently their spacing is too close and looking at it sometimes confuses me.

[image]

Like the first one is cpu temp, 2nd is cpu usage 3rd is gpu temp and 4th is gpu usage

Searched some threads but can't find how to do it, some people even added label names not sure if that is even possible. But at the least the ability to add some space in between the labels would be nice